# .reg file issue - not changing registry

Tags: windows-10, registry

I've made this reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Blizzard Entertainment\Diablo II]
"InstallPath"="g:\Standalone\Diablo2 1.13D"
```

When I run it I get info that values were successfully added to registry but when I check it, it still holds old value. What can be the cause of that and how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

In registry you need to escape file paths so it should be:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Blizzard Entertainment\Diablo II]
"InstallPath"="g:\\Standalone\\Diablo2 1.13D"